# Inequality word problem: Marty's weekend planning

Tags: inequality

"Write and Solve an inequality.

Marty is planning his weekend. He plans to sped half as much time doing homework as he spends playing video games. He plans to spend three times as many hours napping as he spends doing homework. He is also planning to see a 2 hour movie with his friends. If he had at most 12 hours of free time this weekend, what is the most number of hours he can spend playing video games?"

I know how to solve inequalities, I am just clueless as to how to write the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Identify your variables:
$h=$ hours spent on homework,
$v=$ hours spent on video games,
$n=$ hours spent napping.

2.) Translate the second, third, and fifth sentences into algebraic expressions:

"He plans to spend half as much times doing homework as he spends playing video games." Since $v$ is the hours spent playing video games, then the hours spent doing homework is half that, so $h=\frac{1}{2}v$.

"He plans to spend three times as many hours napping as he spends doing homework." Can you apply the same logic if $n$ is the number hours spent napping?

"If he had at most 12 hours of free time this weekend, what is the most number of hours he can spend playing video games?" We know 2 of those hours will be spent at a movie, so the remaining 10 hours must be spent on napping, video games, and homework. Thus $$n+v+h\le10.$$ Can you use the information from the other two statements to rewrite this expression in terms of $v$?

Comment: For the second sentence, n would be 3h. Then, I don't know how to rewrite the expression in terms of v.

Comment: But you also know that $h=(1/2) v$.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I plug (1/2)$v into 3h, and I would get (3/2)v. Then, the equation would be (1/2)v+v+(3/2)v=10. @laarshelenius

Comment: Well $(1/2)v+v+(3/2)v\le 10$, but yes, that's correct! Now just solve for $v$ and you are all set!